# Was there a magical source behind the heatwave in Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix (2007)*, temperature is too hot:

[image: Mrs Dursley sweating, while watching a weather report on a TV screen]

What's the reason behind hot temperature ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The source novel indicates that it's simply the height of summer in the UK, noting that [1995 was indeed a surprisingly hot summer in real life](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_heat_waves).

No additional explanation (e.g. that it's *magically* hot) is offered by the author.

> *The hottest day of the sum­mer so far was draw­ing to a close and a drowsy si­lence lay over the large, square hous­es of Priv­et Drive. Cars that were usu­al­ly gleam­ing stood dusty in their drives and lawns that were once emer­ald green lay parched and yel­low­ing -for the use of hosepipes had been banned due to drought. De­prived of their usu­al car-​wash­ing and lawn-​mow­ing pur­suits, the in­hab­itants of Priv­et Drive had re­treat­ed in­to the shade of their cool hous­es*.

Comment: The English are historically ill-equipped to cope with temperatures above about 30 degrees Celsius, prompting headlines about it being ' a scorcher' and a headlong rush to spend time on the beach for the four and a half minutes a year when it's pleasant to do so.

Comment: additionally, if we consider the opening of OotP to take place in 1995 - that was also the year of a real-life record breaking heat wave in England - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_heat_waves

Comment: @Valorum As a Brit I can confirm. Our houses are built to keep heat in, not out, and it is very rare that businesses, let alone houses, will have air conditioning. I was trying to travel out of Manchester Piccadilly once when temperatures above 25 degrees celsius were apparently causing the tracks and electricity cables to warp, leading to many delays.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Cheers for reminding me. I've edited accordingly. That year was scorcher.

Comment: It's all relative - used to be 15°C was a t-shirt and shorts - now I moved down under I'll be rugged up in a jumper and fleece.